# How to get value in JSON?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typeerror

I'm trying to make a Discord bot and will apply commands from JSON file (for ex. if command is "abc", find "abc" in commands' array (list) and reply with abc's data). Here an element from my JSON file (file is long, because of this, haven't put full file):

```
[
    {"howareyou": {
        "Reply": "**Uh, oh... A few minutes ago lost my diamond banana from Middle Ages. But expect this, I'm OK.",
        "NoArguments": true
    }}
]
```

But the problem is: I get error "Cannot read property "Reply" of undefined" at this JS code:

```
const CMDFile = JSON.parse (FS.readFileSync ('./Commands.json', 'utf8', Error_ => { if (Error_) throw Error_ }))

if (Message.content.startsWith ('\\')) { // My prefix is '\'
    if (Used_CMD == '' /* Used CMD is msg content without prefix */ || (Message.mentions.users.first () && Message.mentions.users.first ().id == '123456789012345678')) {
            Cevapla ('Yes, I'm! For more, just use command `\\help`.')
    } else {
        const CMD = CMDFile [Used_CMD],
              Reply = CMD.Reply, NoArg = CMD.NoArguments
```

My code runs correctly when I use '\' command btw, but when I type '\howareyou', it errors `TypeError: Cannot read property 'Reply' of undefined`. How can I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is either the format of your input file, or the code to get the proper command from the JSON.

1. **either** change your input file to :

```
{
    "howareyou": {
        "Reply": "**Uh, oh... A few minutes ago lost my diamond banana from Middle Ages. But expect this, I'm OK.",
        "NoArguments": true
    },
    "other_cmd": {
        "Reply": "xx",
        "NoArguments": true
    }
}
```

2. **or** find the command from the current structure :

```
var CMD = null
CMDFile.forEach((cmd) => { if(cmd.hasOwnProperty(Used_CMD)) CMD = cmd; });
```

or (as per comment)

```
const CMD = CMDFile.find(cmd => cmd.hasOwnProperty(Used_CMD));
```

Comment: I think [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead of `forEach` would be more suitable for the second solution

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't the `.forEach(...)` pretty much an overkill here? Can't you just do `let commandData = readJsonData[usedCommandName];`?

Comment: Also, keep in mind that currently this will return a parsed `object` for you, not an array, so you can't use either `find` or `forEach` anyway, just to clear things up for people looking at both solutions.

Comment: @IanH. I've clarified with "either/or"